# Applying Leibniz (Alternating Series) Test to Determine Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a few questions about applying Leibniz (Alternating Series) Test and hope you can help me with that.
As an example I will use the following series : 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n ((-1)^{9n}n^2e^{\frac{-n^2}{3}})$$

- When looking at $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^{9n}n^2e^{\frac{-n^2}{3}}$ I don't quite understand what can be done with $(-1)^{9n}$. Without it , I could have easily found the limit using L'Hospital's rule and proven that it is indeed approaches $0$ (as needed). Should I instead look at $\lim_{n\to \infty}|a_n|$ then?
- I also don't understand how I can prove that $a_n>0$ if it actually depends on $(-1)^{9n}$. Am I doing something wrong here as well?

I don't need the complete solution as know that it is converges. I do hope, however , that you can help me to understand this test better.

P.S. (I remember about the decreasing series condition, but I decided to skip it here as it is not related to my main questions)

Answer (score 1):

Well, $(-1)^{9n}=(-1)^n$. Besides, $\left(n^2e^{-\frac{n^2}3}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is decreasing. So…

Answer (score 0):

$$  (-1)^{9n} = (-1)^n(-1)^{8n} = (-1)^n  \text{.}  $$

Comment: I do understand that, but how can it help me prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n$ approaches 0? My main question is basically about the sign there. How can I find the limit if the sign depends on n which approaches infinity?

Comment: @Alex.Kh Well you said " I don't quite understand what can be done with $(-1)^{9n}$. Without it , I could have easily found the limit using L'Hospital's rule and proven that it is indeed approaches $0$ (as needed)." so hat directly answers the first point you've raised, right?

Comment: @Alex.Kh : You say you do not need any help showing the sequence decreases.  "(I remember about the decreasing series condition, but I decided to skip it here as it is not related to my main questions)".  This is the *alternating* series test.  There should be a component that causes the sign to alternate and the remainder which should (eventually) go to zero.  You claim to understand the second part.

Comment: @EricTowers are you saying than that I just have to forget for a moment about the alternating part and simply disregard the sign during analysis ? If so, it is not hard to understand the remaining solution.

Comment: @Alex.Kh : Do you not have a [clear statement of the alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)?

Answer (score 0):

One more:

$(-1)^{9n}=((-1)^9)^n=(-1)^n$.